# Do I need to add a ground wire from house panel to a workshop sub-panel?

Tags: electrical

I read that if a workshop was wired before 2007 from the service panel in the house to a sub-panel in a workshop that 3 wires were ok. My workshop only has 3 wires from the main panel. Is this ok or do I need to use 4 wires, instead of 3?

Comment: Are the 3 wires **in metallic conduit the whole way?** What was the code in effect in your area at the time that it was built or wired?

Comment: Does your workshop have a sub-panel? Is the breaker feeding it a two-pole breaker, or a single-width breaker? We tend to assume a full 240V subpanel, but one possibility for a smaller workshop is that you have only a 120V feed with Hot, Neutral and Ground wires.

Answer (score 2):

For reasons of **safety**, (which is why code was changed) a ground is good to have. That can be a 4th wire, or it can be a complete metallic conduit enclosing the 3 wires you may already have, and not recognize as a ground (it is a code-legal ground conductor.)

For *legalistic quibbling* about "do you need to retrofit a ground" you need to know at what date the shop was either built, or connected to electricity, and what code was adopted by your Local Area Having Jurisdiction on that date. Some LAHJs adopt new code revisions very quickly. Others are still using the 2008 code in 2023. Many LAHJs adopt the code, but with local changes. For instance, many places that have adopted NEC2020 have changed the AFCI/GFCI requirements somewhat because supplies of two-pole GFCIs/AFCIs newly called for in the 2020 code were or are somewhat inadequate as yet.